# Multiple IF THEN in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have three columns of data... column 1 has TRUE or FALSE, column 2 has TRUE or FALSE, and column 3 has one of the following letters:  A, S, M or E.

I am looking for a formula that will return:

```
FALSE and FALSE = 0%
TRUE and FALSE = 3%
TRUE and TRUE and A = 5%
TRUE and TRUE and S = 8%
TRUE and TRUE and M = 10%
TRUE and TRUE and E = 15%
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use deeply nested if statement:

```
=if(and(A=False,B=False),0%,
 if(A=True,if(B=False,3%,
 if(C="A",5%,
 if(C="S",8%,
 if(C="M",10%,
 if(C="E",15%)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

=IF(A1=FALSE,0%,IF(B1=FALSE,3%,IF(C1="E",15%,IF(C1="M",10%,IF(C1="S",8%,5%)))))

If you want the percentages formatted as text, put all of them in quote marks. If you want them as a number, but not as a decimal, be sure to format your cells to display percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Without nested IFs:

```
=IF(A1<>B1,.03,CHOOSE(MATCH(C1,{"A";"S";"M";"E"},0),.05,.08,.1,.15))*(A1=TRUE)
```

(subject to formatting).